# Is there a way to save the palette in the "Save for Web" feature of Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I would like to apply a single palette to multiple images, is there a way to easily save and retrieve a special palette in the save for web feature. There is this option that you can switch colors when you click on them, but can you store them?

Or should I do this entirely different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the little arrow and three lines opens a menu that has save options:

[image]

[image]